How to create a projection in clickhouse for the ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree engine table?
clickhouse version 24.8.8.17
I can't create a projection
Is it generally efficient to create a projection for this engine? Or is a materialized view an alternative?
trying to create a projection:
CREATE TABLE test_a (
src String, 
dst String, 
other_cols String 
) 
ENGINE =ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree('/shard', 'replica') ORDER BY src;

ALTER TABLE test_a ADD PROJECTION test_projection 
(SELECT * ORDER BY dst);

I encounter an error:
Code: 344. DB::Exception: Projection is fully supported in ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree with deduplicate_merge_projection_mode = throw. Use 'drop' or 'rebuild' option of deduplicate_merge_projection_mode. (SUPPORT_IS_DISABLED)

Help please

read error message
use ALTER TABLE test_a ADD PROJECTION test_projection  (SELECT * ORDER BY dst) SETTINGS deduplicate_merge_projection_mode='rebuild'
